# Proof of R is transitive if and only if $R^{-1}$ is transitive.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:Let R be a realation in a set X. Prove that $R$  is transitive if and if only if $R^{-1}$  is transitive.

My proof

$R$ is transitive 
≡ [(x, y)∈R∧(y, z)∈R⇒(x, z)∈R]         by the def. of a transitive relation

≡ [(y, x)∈$R^{-1}$∧(z, y)∈$R^{-1}$⇒(y, y)∈$R^{-1}$] by def. of an inverse relation

≡ $R^{-1}$ is transitive            by the def. of a transitive relation

It seems I proved the statement is true. But I have an uncanny feeling that something is strange because the proof has a reflexive relation (y, y)∈$R^{-1}$, while its purpose is to gain a transitive relation from another transitive relation.

Would you prove the same way as I do? Or can you either show another way or point out mistakes in my proof?

FYI
Let R be a relation from A to B. Then inverse $R^{-1}$ of the relation R is the relation from B to A such that $bR^{-1}a$ if and only if $aRb$. That is, $R^{-1}$ ={(b, a) | (a, b) ∈R}

R is transitive if and only if xRy∧yRz⇒xRz.

Comment: In the 2nd line of your proof you have to correct (y, y)∈R−1...

Answer (score 2):

Look at it as:

$$\text{$R$ is transitive } \iff \\ (\forall \ x,y,z)[ (x,y) \in R \land (y,z) \in R \implies (x,z) \in R] \iff \\ (\forall \ x,y,z)[ (y,x) \in R^{-1} \land (z,y) \in R^{-1} \implies (z,x) \in R^{-1}] \iff \\ (\forall \ x,y,z)[ (z,y) \in R^{-1} \land (y,x) \in R^{-1} \implies (z,x) \in R^{-1}] \iff \\ \text{$R^{-1}$ is transitive}  $$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

For the ⇒) direction, you have to start with $(z,y)∈R^{−1}$ and $(y,x)∈R^{−1}$, to conclude with : $(z, x)∈R^{−1}$.

From the assumption, by definition of $R^{−1}$, it follows that :

> $(x,y)∈R$ and $(y,z)∈R$.

Now you have to apply the *transitivity* of $R$.

Comment: According to your hint, I can get this modified proof in the second step  [(z, y)∈$R^{-1}$∧(y, x)∈$R^{-1}$⇒(z, x)∈$R^{-1}$] by def. of an inverse relation, commutative law of logic

Comment: @buzzee - exactly.